# Aliasing with reserved keyword or command alias? (Overwriting)

Tags: security, alias

Is it possible to make an alias with a name that is already reserved as a keyword/command in Linux and Ubuntu?

If I alias `passwd` or `chpasswd` with the same name but use additional parameters so that my server users can change password with usual and default command lines but under the hood they are making them more stronger than appears outside?

Comment: Yes you can, but they can ignore it and run it like : `\passwd` to use it without additional parameters.

Comment: Further to what @Ravexina says, you can also - on your own system (one you are the "root" superuser on) - simply replace the `passwd` or `chpasswd`, rather than alias them. Your replacement script could use the original script in the background, for example, or could bypass them altogether, it's your system!